# Lambdas dont implicity convert when using in class constructors

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, function-pointers

I am trying to make a simple implementation of the `std::function`

The following code works with function pointers and lambdas which are explicitly converted.

```
template<typename funct>
class functor {
private:
    funct *function;
public:
    functor() = default;
    functor(funct *func) : function(func) {};

    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T a, T b){
        return function(a, b);
    }
};

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::map<std::string, functor<int(int,int)>> maps = { {"+", add} };
    maps.insert({ "%", {[](int i, int j)->int { return i * j; } } } );
    auto temp = maps["%"](5,6);
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
 }
```

I want to know why lambdas don't work with implicit conversion.

```
maps.insert({ "%", [](int i, int j)->int { return i * j; } }  );
```

The above code doesn't work but the following does:

```
maps.insert({ "%", {[](int i, int j)->int { return i * j; } } } );
```

but the `std::function` works with `{}` and without.

Comment: `std::function` has a templated constructor.

Comment: @KerrekSB Speaks wisdom.....having a templated constructor could allow you to do what you are trying to do.....that said I don't know how `std::function` accomplishes the same goals.

Comment: Another thing to consider is lambdas are not function objects. You may convert a lambda into a function object but they are different and this also may be an intentional reason why there is no implicit conversion. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586756/why-doesnt-c11-implicitly-convert-lambdas-to-stdfunction-objects

Comment: Try `maps.emplace("%", [](int i, int j)->int { return i * j; });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KerrekSB mentioned in the comments, just give your `functor` a templated constructor like this:

```
template<class F>
functor(F f) : function(f) {}
```

Now you can omit the braces when initializing the map:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename funct>
class functor {
private:
    funct *function;
public:
    functor() = default;

    template<class F>
    functor(F f) : function(f) {}

    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T a, T b){
        return function(a, b);
    }
};

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::map<std::string, functor<int(int,int)>> maps = { {"+", add} };
    maps.insert({ "%", [](int i, int j)->int { return i * j; } }  );
    auto temp = maps["%"](5,6);
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
 }
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7acbb03a08e6cd18)