# Lambda closure lvalues can be passed as rvalue reference parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, c++14, rvalue-reference

I found that `lvalue` lambda closures can always be passed as `rvalue` function parameters.

See the following simple demonstration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void foo(std::function<void()>&& t)
{
}

int main()
{
    // Case 1: passing a `lvalue` closure
    auto fn1 = []{};
    foo(fn1);                          // works

    // Case 2: passing a `lvalue` function object
    std::function<void()> fn2 = []{};
    foo(fn2);                          // compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Case 2 is the standard behavior (I just used a `std::function` for demonstration purposes, but any other type would behave the same).

How and why does case 1 work ? What is the state of `fn1` closure after the function returned ?

Comment: I guess that is because `fn1` is implicitly converted to a `std::function` in `foo(fn1)`. That temporary function then is a rvalue.

Comment: @RichardCritten I really wasn't sure, so I didn't post an answer. I think now there is no need for another one.

Comment: @eike np I often feel the same way, and yup many answers.

Comment: I didn't read details yet, but doesn't this question contradict this claim [Why doesn't C++11 implicitly convert lambdas to std::function objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586756/why-doesnt-c11-implicitly-convert-lambdas-to-stdfunction-objects)

Comment: @Sumudu The person who asked the question misled you because they didn't know what they were trying to ask. What they meant to ask was: "Why cannot template arguments of `std::function` be deduced from a lambda". Your program does not attempt to deduce the template arguments of `std::function`, so there is no problem with the implicit conversion.

Comment: The title of the question you linked is a little misleading. `std::function` has a non-explicit constructor that accepts lambda closures, so there is implicit conversion. But in the circumstances of the linked question, the template instantiation of `std::function` cannot be inferred from the lambda type. (For example `std::function<void()>` can be constructed from `[](){return 5;}` even though it has a non-void return type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How and why does case 1 work ?

Invoking `foo` requires an instance of `std::function<void()>` that binds to an *rvalue reference*. `std::function<void()>` can be constructed from any *callable object* that is compatible with the `void()` signature.

Firstly, a temporary `std::function<void()>` object is constructed from `[]{}`. The constructor used is #5 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), which copies the closure into the `std::function` instance:

> ```
> template< class F >
> function( F f );
> ```
>
> Initializes the target with `std::move(f)`. If `f` is a null pointer to function or null pointer to member, `*this` will be empty after the call.

Then, the temporary `function` instance is bound to the rvalue reference.

---

> What is the state of fn1 closure after the function returned ?

Same as before, because it was copied into a `std::function` instance. The original closure is unaffected.

Answer (score 9):

A lambda is not a `std::function`. The reference doesn't bind *directly*.

Case 1 works because lambdas are convertible to `std::function`s. This means that a temporary `std::function` is materialized by *copying* `fn1`. Said temporary is able to be bound to an rvalue reference, and so the argument matches the parameter.

And the copying is also why `fn1` is entirely unaffected by anything that happens in `foo`.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the state of fn1 closure after the function returned ?

`fn1` is stateless, since it captures nothing.

> How and why does case 1 work ?

It works because the argument is of different type than the type that is rvalue referenced. Because of having a different type, implicit conversions are considered. Since the lambda is Callable for the arguments of this `std::function`, it is implicitly convertible to it through the template converting constructor of `std::function`. The result of the conversion is a prvalue, and thus can be bound with the rvalue reference.